# IntelliJ - code with "expand all" by default

Tags: intellij-idea

Question please on IntelliJ.

Currently, IntelliJ "folds" code that are one liners. Something like:

```
public String getFoo() { return foo; }
```

A insist, it is just a visual. On the file itself, it is not folded, just on the visual of the IDE.

```
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
```

On Mac, on each start of IntelliJ, I am currently selecting all files and pressing "shift" + "command + "plus sign +" to expand all files.

Is there a way to have by default files with expand all?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable these settings:

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Code Folding | Simple property accessors
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Code Folding | One-line methods

[image: disable folding]